# Making a Sprite unmovable...[Chipmunk & Cocos2D]

Tags: ipad, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

Im using Chipmunk with Cocos2d to make a gravity based puzzle game, however I have reached a part of my project whereby I need a sprite that once drawn does not move and cannot be moved by the other sprites within the environment.

In essence...

Can I create a static (non moving) sprite that is not affected by in game gravity or other objects in the game.

*Thanks in advance I've only been doing this project a week....*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

1) Create a body with infinite mass and moment.

2) Do *not* add the body to the space.

3) Create the desired shape.

Use `cpSpaceAddStaticShape` to add the shape to the space.